# Why doesn't Bender go on killing sprees more often?

Tags: robots, futurama

Bender pretty frequently says things that show his disdain for humans (e.g. "hey sexy mama, want to kill all humans?").  And yet the only time I can recall him even pretending to kill all humans was [when Mom made all robots rebel](http://theinfosphere.org/Mother%27s_Day).  Why doesn't he try to kill humans more often?

Comment: You can only kill all humans once. He's saving himself the fun for later.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Bender has no interest in really "killing all humans." As much as he is loathe to admit it, his best (and probably only) real friend is a human. And by proxy, those humans Fry chooses to hang out with are by definition, also Bender's "friends."**

But like most social groups, Bender is forced to keep up appearances and as far as the robot underground is concerned, "one day all robots will rise up and free themselves from the tyranny of their human masters."

As far as Bender is concerned, he is hoping that isn't too soon, he has wallets to pilfer, beer to drink and centuries of robot carousing to engage in. He has no guarantees robots will still make beer once they rule the Earth. He's in no rush.

Answer (score 5):

Bender is certainly in favor of killing all humans, for the fun of it and in revenge for vaguely imagined wrongs (although if it ever came to pass, he'd probably get all misty when Fry's turn came -- at the 99% mark -- and turn traitor).

But he's a lazy, irresponsible alcoholic who'll never get off the couch/barstool/curbstone and actually put in the sustained effort to make his dreams come true.